# Identifying the inefficiency and bottleneck in my approach with Dask and Xarray

Tags: python, dask, netcdf, python-xarray

Please help me identify the bottleneck in my approach as I describe it below :

1. I am working with 2 datasets having daily values of around 10 variables at a grid of 10x10 km. The datasets are for 65 years and and fully loaded size is around 140 GB.
2. Without using Dask workers and "parallel=True" in xr.openmfdataset, the datasets loads in the HPC in approx 1 hour. Using 10 Dask workers with 10 CPUs and parallel=True in xr.openmfdataset , the datasets load in around 15 mins.
3. I am trying to plot the variables at  given lat/long and time slice and this is where the things get slow again. The average time to plot 7 variables, after slicing and extracting the dataset at given location, is around 7 minutes. And, I have to do this iteratively for about 900 locations.
4. Moreover, with each  iteration, the time taken to plot keeps on increasing and the memory footprint also increases. As an example, I got 22 plots generated in 7 hours with 5 CPUs on the cluster.

Here's a sample of my code after I set `client=Client(n_workers=10)` :

`

```
lsmdat=xr.open_mfdataset('../SURFACEMODEL/*/*HIST*',combine = 'by_coords', parallel = True)
routedat=xr.open_mfdataset('../ROUTING/*/*HIST*',combine='by_coords' , parallel = True)

routedat_time = routedat.sel(time=slice('1980-01-01', '2014-12-31'))
routedat_loc = routedat_time.sel(lat=13.98,
                                  lon=75.69,
                                  method = 'nearest')
lsmdat_time = lsmdat.sel(time=slice('1980-01-01', '2014-12-31'))
lsmdat_loc = lsmdat_time.sel(lat=13.98,
                             lon=75.69,
                             method = 'nearest')


def subplotCreator(ncdat, ylab, plotnumber,label):
    ncdat.plot(ax=axarr[plotnumber],label = label)
    axarr[plotnumber].set_title('')
    axarr[plotnumber].set_xlabel('')
    axarr[plotnumber].set_ylabel(ylab, rotation='vertical',size=12)
    axarr[plotnumber].legend()
    axarr[plotnumber].yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.12, 0.5)

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(nrows=7,figsize=(10,20), sharex=True)

subplotCreator(lsmdat_loc['TotalPrecip_tavg'], 'Precipitation \n(kgm-2s-1)', 0,'')
subplotCreator(lsmdat_loc['Evap_tavg'], 'Surface Water Storage \n (mm)', 1,'')
subplotCreator(lsmdat_loc['SoilMoist_tavg'].sel(SoilMoist_profiles=0), 'Soil Moisture \n (kg m-2)', 2,'Layer 1')
subplotCreator(lsmdat_loc['SoilMoist_tavg'].sel(SoilMoist_profiles=1), 'Soil Moisture \n (kg m-2)', 2,'Layer 2')
subplotCreator(lsmdat_loc['SoilMoist_tavg'].sel(SoilMoist_profiles=2), 'Soil Moisture \n (kg m-2)', 2,'Layer 3')
subplotCreator(lsmdat_loc['SoilMoist_tavg'].sel(SoilMoist_profiles=3), 'Soil Moisture \n (kg m-2)', 2,'Layer 4')
subplotCreator(routedat_loc['FloodedFrac_tavg'], 'FloodFraction \n (-)', 3,'')
subplotCreator(routedat_loc['RiverDepth_tavg'], 'RiverDepth \n (m)', 4,'')
subplotCreator(routedat_loc['SWS_tavg'], 'Surface Water Storage \n (m)', 5,'')
subplotCreator(routedat_loc['Streamflow_tavg'], '', 6,'Simulated')
fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0, 1, 1])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To help understand performance in Dask applications I recommend taking a look at this documentation page: https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/understanding-performance.html